# Разница (использует promise и async)

Tags: javascript

Подскажите в чем разница? Сколько не пробую, не могу понять. Проимпортированно все корректно, т.к. в остальных местах supMethods.syncTimeout() работает.

Этот код работает

```
function flash (item, time) {
    show(item)
    
    Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        hide(item) && resolve()
        }, time)
    })                  
}
```

А этот нет

```
function flash (item, time) {
    show(item)
    
    supMethods.syncTimeout(hide(item), time)                
}
```

Вот так все вызывается

```
for (const element of this.needNumbers)  {
                await supMethods.syncTimeout(  reproduce(element, this.gameMode === 0 ? 800 : 100) && await flash(element, this.gameMode - 100)
                , 100)
            }
```

Доп функции для понимания

```
export function syncTimeout(func = true, time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      func && resolve()
    }, time)
  })
}

let show = item => this.panels[item -1].classList.add('simon__panel_active')
let hide = item => this.panels[item -1].classList.remove('simon__panel_active')
```

Comment: Спасибо, поменял и вроде даже понял. Прямо рад что спросил в стеке. Ток пишите в следующий раз пож в поле для ответа, а не коментарии, что бы можно было отметить ответ, как правильный ))

Comment: готово :) . в комментариях потому, что мог понять вопрос не верно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во втором случае `hide(item)` срабатывает ещё до того, как сработает промис. Напишите вместо этого `()=> hide(item)`, а внутри промиса вызывайте, а не просто упоминайте функцию. Ну и `&&` - плохой подход, лучше точка с запятой или условие.

Ещё замечу, что `syncTimeout` асинхронный, название вводит в заблуждение. Промис всегда асинхронный, несмотря на `await`. А синхронный делал бы блокировку выполнения, например долгий цикл. Плюс используется ваш метод потом в обычной функции, никакой синхронности тут нет, функция отработает до того, как выполнится таймер.